# ExFat disk not detected

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I'm trying to connect an external hard drive to my computer (Ubuntu 16.04, dual boot with windows). I checked and the disk is working on other computers. It was also working on mine before, and for some reason, it stopped being detected and mounted automatically.

The external hard drive was formated in exFat using another computer with Mac OS X. The weird part is that if I let it plugged long enough, suddenly it is mounted automatically by the computer (after several minutes), and then it works like a charm.

When plugged, the disk doesn't appear in fdisk or others lsblk,...
Dmesg output is however logging the disk connection:

```
[  120.266550] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  120.283365] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1062
[  120.283377] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  120.283386] usb 2-4: Product: Rugged USB3 THB
[  120.283392] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: LaCie
[  120.283397] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 0000000015ac2c7500d7
[  120.300185] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  120.303319] scsi host0: uas
[  120.303408] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  120.304404] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LaCie    Rugged THB USB3  051E PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  120.304845] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  124.445048] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  124.445065] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  124.445649] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  124.445676] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  124.446023] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

Then, it starts doing this repeatedly:

```
[  154.859957] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[  154.859989] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 12 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[  154.860160] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  154.972264] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  154.995589] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
...
[  309.873009] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[  309.873026] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 93 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[  309.873172] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  309.985460] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  310.003272] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[  340.849898] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[  340.849901] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 93 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[  340.849985] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  340.962449] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  340.979668] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[  360.178643] INFO: task systemd-udevd:2263 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.178667]       Not tainted 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu
[  360.178674] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  360.178681] systemd-udevd   D ffff88003fb7bc88     0  2263    264 0x00000004
[  360.178698]  ffff88003fb7bc88 00000000fffffffa ffffffff81e11500 ffff8804e55be740
[  360.178711]  ffff88003fb7c000 0000000000000000 ffff8804dae68140 ffffffffc06f6500
[  360.178723]  ffff8800d280ecc0 ffff88003fb7bca0 ffffffff81830f15 ffffffffffffffff
[  360.178735] Call Trace:
[  360.178762]  [<ffffffff81830f15>] schedule+0x35/0x80
[  360.178780]  [<ffffffff810a355e>] async_synchronize_cookie_domain+0x6e/0x150
[  360.178796]  [<ffffffff810c3ed0>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
[  360.178810]  [<ffffffff810a3677>] async_synchronize_full+0x17/0x20
[  360.178826]  [<ffffffff8118ce35>] do_init_module+0xc1/0x1cf
[  360.178838]  [<ffffffff8110a3ef>] load_module+0x166f/0x1c10
[  360.178849]  [<ffffffff81106990>] ? __symbol_put+0x60/0x60
[  360.178866]  [<ffffffff81213a80>] ? kernel_read+0x50/0x80
[  360.178880]  [<ffffffff8110abd4>] SYSC_finit_module+0xb4/0xe0
[  360.178892]  [<ffffffff8110ac1e>] SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[  360.178905]  [<ffffffff81834ff2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[  371.827287] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[  371.827308] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 93 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[  371.827573] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[  371.940129] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  371.958671] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
```

... It does this whole thing a bunch of times, and then suddenly:

```
[ 1208.910101] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[ 1208.910116] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 41 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[ 1208.910235] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[ 1209.022845] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1209.039727] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[ 1239.951073] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[ 1239.951077] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Report supported operation codes a3 0c 01 41 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[ 1239.951120] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[ 1240.063369] usb 2-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1240.081349] scsi host0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[ 1240.081428] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

And after that the disk works perfectly.

What is happening here? I looked and looked on forums and couldn't find anything. It would be great if someone had a solution so that the disk would just be detected and mounted like any normal disk, without taking all this time and sometimes suddenly working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this problem, anyone would have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: I had already tried reinstalling exfat-fuse and exfat-utils. Just in case I did it again with your command (adding the missing - before reinstall), but it did not change anything... Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem with mounting appeared after I used SSD on Windows. Once I came back to Ubuntu, the mount point "/mnt/sdb1" started to be incorrect (Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Operation not permitted).

What worked out for me was:

```
sudo mkdir /media/exfat
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/exfat
```

Or you can also turn on "User Session Defaults" in Disks and the external drive should mount properly.

[image]